# Printing Datagridview value

Tags: vb.net

when i print this from Datagridview the values are on top of one another,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcOWp.jpg)

```
Dim rowCount As Integer = DataGridView6.Rows.Count
For i = 0 To rowCount - 1

    e.Graphics.DrawString("PARTICULARS", ReportBodyFont, Brushes.Black, 70, 300)
    e.Graphics.DrawString("QTY", ReportBodyFont, Brushes.Black, 400, 300)
    e.Graphics.DrawString("AMOUNT", ReportBodyFont, Brushes.Black, 600, 300)

    e.Graphics.DrawString("----------------------------------------------------------", ReportFont, Brushes.Black, 50, 310)
    ''
    e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView6.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value, ReportBodyFont, Brushes.Black, 50, 320)
    e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView6.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value, ReportBodyFont, Brushes.Blue, 400, 320)
    e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView6.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value, ReportBodyFont, Brushes.Black, 600, 320)

Next
```

Comment: You should measure the `ReportBodyFont` height in the current device context (`e.Graphics.MeasureString()`) and calculate the new line position based on that value, plus an Interline, if you have set one.

Comment: I said that you should edit your question, not my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course they are. You're using the exact same coordinates for every row. If you expect each row to be printed below the previous one then you need to specify a Y that is greater than the previous one. Generally speaking, you would establish a baseline for the first record and the height of a record and then use a Y coordinate for each row that is that baseline plus the row index multiplied by the height, e.g.

```vb
Dim y0 = 10
Dim rowHeight = 50

For rowIndex = 0 To rowCount - 1
    Dim y = y0 + rowIndex * rowHeight

    'Print at y.
Next
```

Comment: Long code snippets in comments are bad. Unformatted code snippets in comments are bad. Code snippets with no explanation or context in comments are bad. I don't know whether you're asking me something or telling me something or neither. Try taking the time to explain yourself fully and clearly, so we don't have to guess or assume or otherwise waste time trying to work out what you mean. If you need to provide more information, that should generally be done by editing the question.

Comment: it didnt work for me please help me with this issue.